# Problem on press create button 2 times and data stored 2 times

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a big problem about creating a record for attendance check_in in Database. I am using the current DATE - TIME - LOCATION for storing the information of the attendance into Database. When user press check_in in mobile app, it will store the attendance record into database and return success message. But when user press check_in 2nd time, it should return the message "Already checked in" but the record is still created.

This is my code in User.php

```
public function checkIn()
    {
        $exists = Attendance::where('attendance_date' , Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->whereNotNull('scan_in_time')
            ->where('created_at' , date(now()))
            ->exists();
        if($exists){
            return false;
        }

        return $this->attendance()->create([
            'attendance_date' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'),
            'scan_in_time' => Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s'),
            'attendance_status' => DB::RAW("CASE
                WHEN scan_in_time >= '08:30:00' AND scan_in_time < '09:00:00' THEN '2'
                WHEN scan_in_time > '09:00:00' AND scan_in_time < '17:00:00' THEN '3' ELSE '1' END"),
            'scan_in_location' => request()->scan_in_location,
            'scan_in_remarks' => request()->scan_in_remarks
        ]);
    }
```

And this is in AttendanceController:

```
public function check_in(Request $request)
    {
        $attendance = $request->user()->checkIn();

        if($attendance){
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Fail',
            ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Success',
//                'data' => $attendance
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I dont know are there any mistakes in handling duplicated record in this one. Can you give me some advise on how to change this code for handling duplicated record, should be return "Already checked in" via Mobile UI

Comment: You could either do a check to see if they've checked-in recently (instead of `now()`) and/or disable the button when a check-in has been confirmed.

Comment: This because i am testing in postman so i am checking the duplicated. This is I write for API handling check_in when Mobile call API from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your user function `checkIn` don't use `->where('created_at' , date(now()))` in the `exists` query, because that's always new time, no matter how quick you clicked, you are not faster than a millisecond. And you also don't check if the same user has checked in at the same location.

So as an example in your exists query check for the same user at the same location in the last 5 minutes if he checked in with the following query:

```
Attendance::where('attendance_date' , Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('user_id', $this->id)
        ->where('scan_in_location', request()->scan_in_location)
        ->whereNotNull('scan_in_time')
        ->whereBetween('created_at' , [Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5), Carbon::now()])
        ->exists();
```

Comment: with this way, i can handle for create many times but in record it is only 1. But the message could be wrong because for the first time i check_in, the json with message => Success, but when it is the 2nd time, it should be Fail. But why it is still success?

Comment: @HuyNguyen Because your condition in the controller is wrong. You return `false` from the `checkIn` function and then you display `Failed` if you have returned true. So switch the response in your controller.